# UI Bootstrap's typeahead refuses to iterate through object

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

According to docs found on official ui-bootstrap, typeahead directive "uses the same, flexible syntax as the [select directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect)"

But unfortunatelly it seems that typeahead directive refuses to iterate through object sources using the following list of syntaxes supported by `select`

```
for object data sources:

label for (key , value) in object
select as label for (key , value) in object
label group by group for (key, value) in object
select as label group by group for (key, value) in object
```

I think that UI-Bootstrap's `ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.4.0.js` need to be edited (somewhere around line `2749`) to allow this kind of functionality

So my question is what is angular and ui-bootstrap-friendly approach to implementing this functionality, (I can do it by replacing the `.length` with something that is more object-friendly, but I guess that there are lot more better ways of supporting the `select` object datasource syntax, than I can provide)

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, the current implementation of the typeahead directive from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ works only on sources that are arrays, so there is no way to iterate over objects. I've opened an issue to clarify this in the documentation:
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/715

The culprit is this piece of code, really: 
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/typeahead/typeahead.js#L109-L115

While switching it to the `angular.forEach` would make the situation better, the main problem is that built-in AngularJS filters won't work on objects... So you would have to write your own matching logic as well. This is why I've decided to drop support for the `(key, value)` syntax.

**Currently your best option is to convert your object to an array**.

So I'm going to update the docs to make it clear what is supported and what is not. But if you can see a perfect solution here, feel free to send a pull request!

Comment: Ok, I see, thanks, but does this mean that `select` also does not support filtering for objects? I have already modified the regular expression that did the parsing of typeahead contents, and were looking to start modifying the code that did that parsing, but as far as I understood it's a pretty small fish to fry, and there will be no benefit in the end?